# Script won't load in wordpress footer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to do something which should be very simple, but keeps bugging me.
I have the following code in functions.php:

```
// Load HTML5 Blank conditional scripts
function html5blank_conditional_scripts(){
    if (!is_single()) {
      wp_register_script('imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', true); // Conditional script(s)
      wp_enqueue_script('imagesloaded'); // Enqueue it!

      wp_register_script('masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/masonry.pkgd.min.js', true); // Conditional script(s)
      wp_enqueue_script('masonry'); // Enqueue it!

      wp_register_script('soinit', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/soinit.js', true); // Conditional script(s)
      wp_enqueue_script('soinit'); // Enqueue it!
    }

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'html5blank_conditional_scripts'); // Add Conditional Page Scripts
```

Main problem here is: 'imagesloaded' and 'masonry' scripts are successfully added to the footer, while the 'soinit' script keeps getting added to the head

Comment: Because it is `init` script?

Comment: @FlashThunder I can call it however I like, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the functions is:

```
wp_register_script( string $handle, string $src, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

so you need to provide all the parameters even if they are empty

```
wp_register_script( 'soinit', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/soinit.js', '', '',  true);
```

Comment: I don't get why I should override the default values, but it does work, thanks.

Comment: you are not overriding the default values, the function aspects every argument in its specific position, if you pass `true` as third argument the function assumes you are passing `$deps = true` and that's an error...